# Changing background color in Outlook

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there any way to change background color of every message I receive in Outlook. By default color is white. I would like to make it gray.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook, the sender controls the message format (font and all such like) - not the receiver.

So if you wish to change the format and background of the received message, you have to edit it and re-save it.

It is not always possible to edit received messages. I have done it from time to time (rarely, and for specific reasons).

If you wish to try changing all of Office colors, that may help you, but that is not just for messages, that is for all of Office.

Office (say 2016), any Office App, Office Account and then two choices:  Change Background and Change Theme.

Comment: Can I create a rule or something similar? Before the last couple of Outlook updates background color for coming from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Window`

Comment: @John; Hmm, I'm not so sure about that. I think that if the sender uses the default background color and foreground color, and the mail was sent through Outlook, you can alter a setting somewhere to override this. True, if they alter the text color but not the background color, it may look weird and visa versa, but I'm fairly sure this is possible somehow. I think one of my collegues have set his outlook in a dark mode somehow and has this.

Comment: I get lots of emails and where the background has been changed by the sender, I cannot change without editing the message.  Even if the color is changed the message would have to be saved. Otherwise you would have to change the Outlook system color for all of Outlook (even Office).

Comment: @John and how to do that?

Comment: Office (2013 or later) app, Office account and then there are two choices:  Change Background and Change Theme.  I hope that proves helpful

Answer (score 0):

Waht's the version of your Outlook client? According to my experience on my Outlook 365, we could use [Immersive Reader](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/open-immersive-reader-for-outlook-9249595c-4b9d-4f27-9f59-bc590a6152da) to change the page color when I open and read the messages like below:
[image]
[image]

It would work for every receiving message if we enable the Immersive Reader and open the message to read.